# Hypothesis Testing Partly Identifiable Parameters

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Somehow it seems like the less identifiable parameter is easier to hypothesis test.

I have a multivariate normal distribution with the following 4x4 variance-covariance matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&c&0.5&lc0.5\\
c&1&lc0.5&0.5\\
0.5&lc0.5&1&c\\
lc0.5&0.5&c&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Sometimes $c$ is by itself, and other  times $lc$ occur together. So c will be whatever value it is to maximize the likelihood from the $c$ term and then $l$ will be whatever value necessary to get the term $lc$ to its optimal value.

Yet, it seems easy to hypothesis test $H_0:l=0$ v. $H_1:l\neq0$ but impossible to test $H_0:c=0$ v. $H_1:c\neq0$.  Is it true that a hypothesis about the value of $c$ cannot be tested and only a hypothesis either about $l$ alone or the product $lc$? And if so, why?

Also, I'm thinking of doing the test with AIC.  What is the k-value for a test about lc? 2? and if so, what do I do about the value c which also must take a value?  What about this hypothesis test: $H_0:c,l=0$ v. $H_1:c\neq0,l\neq0$?